# GRASS init error

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I have installed the GRASS 7.8.7 plugin on QGIS. However, when it loads up the GRASS drop down is available but key functions such as New Mapset etc. are greyed out.

I also get the following error when QGIS loads up.

```
GRASS init error: GRASS was not found in 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 3.28.2/apps/grass/grass78'
(GISBASE), provider and plugin will not work.
```

I also downloaded and installed GRASS 8.2 hoping that would be installable in QGIS. I'm not sure how to make it an available plugin, though?

My current project requires GRASS. Any suggestions on resolving this issue?

Comment: Why not do your analysis directly in GRASS? If you post more details regarding your current project, I'm sure we could help.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a good approach. I have .dxf with contours. I need to create profiles along lines on plan. These will be like long-sections of roads. My plan was to use GRASS to create a DEM and then from that extract the profiles. Is this the best approach?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

(Replying to the comment)

I can see two potential problems here.

1. First the *.dxf format does not necessarily have coordinate reference information. So to begin with I would suggest to use some other software to convert to a GIS format that contains the CRS information (such as geopackage or shapefile). This assumes that you know in advance what the coordinate system of the original *.dxf actually is.
2. Second - the procedure to revert contour lines back to a DEM is often troublesome, and does not give satisfactory results. It would be much better to try to obtain the original DEM that was used to derive the *.dxf contour lines.
3. Please review this [wiki page](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Contour_lines_to_DEM) !

Having said that, you can try the following GRASS commands to build a DEM from contour lines:

```
# After converting the *.dxf to a GIS format, such as geopackage:
# Use that projected contour lines layer to create a new GRASS database
grass -c contours.gpkg <your/home/directory/grassdata>
# Import the contour lines
v.import contours.gpkg output=contours

# As always in GRASS, set the computational region
# Pay careful attention to the resolution parameter below.
# It must be something reasonable based on the size of your contour data. 
g.region -ap vect=contours res=10
# Take a look at the output to make sure it looks OK (i.e. how many rows, columms?)
# Now run the r.surf.contour module
r.surf.contour input=contour output=dem
```

Now, if you have a roads layer, import it in a similar way,

```
v.import roads.gpkg output=roads
```

and run the "Profile surface tool" (In the GUI, under the "Analyze Map" button)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help on this. I've been playing around with and have a solution. Regards.